# Visual Studio Code losing connection to Live Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, devtools, liveserver

I worked on media queries on my website today and all of a sudden my browser won't refresh the site but rather says "No internet. ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.

I am using Visual Studio Code with Live Server by Ritwick Dey.

Console warning says "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
"VM10:6745 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

1 Issue: "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform"

The site is on my laptop and I'm just working on it offline. What the heck is going on here?

I tried removing the queries.css file to see if that would make a difference. It did not.

Any link on the site will take me to this NO INTERNET page if I am in the responsive dimensions part of DevTools. Also when there is any edit to the html or css in VSC it immediately results in this NO INTERNET page appearing and I have to shut down the port and Go Live again.

I also opened the practice website that we are building for the class and the same thing is happening with that one as well. I have checked my html and css files on validator.w3.org and they have all checked out.

I tried changing the settings in VSC to set the browser to Chrome and also tried in Edge with the same results.

I removed the extension from VSC and reinstalled. No results. Please help!

Comment: The console warning is unrelated, it is from an adblocker extension you have installed. I have the same one and it will always do that. The only thing I can think is happening is your internet disconnects for a very short period of time, which disconnects the live server immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into the settings in Devtools and reset.

open Devtools
click the gear icon at right side
scroll to bottom of settings
click "restore defaults and reload"

This made a whole variety of strange problems go away in Devtools and now it works as it should.