# Live server doesn't refresh page in toggle device toolbar menu

Tags: html, google-chrome, sass, vscode-extensions, liveserver

## Live server doesn't refresh page in 'toggle device toolbar' menu

a problem with using Live Server in VScode. In default mode page updates normally, but when I enable 'toggle device toolbar' menu, setting custom dimension (for ex. iphone xr or just 900x1000) and press F5 my page crashes and shows 'ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED' message. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g73do.png)
So I want to check how my website looks like on mobile devices but I can't do it because page crashes. How can I solve this problem? I'll be very thankfull for any advices.

Tried to change json setting in live server, but unsuccessfully

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, and it started out of nowhere, yesterday it was working normally, I even thought it was a problem with the live server, but since it happened to you some time ago, I think it must be our problem

[Visual Studio Code losing connection to Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74947773/visual-studio-code-losing-connection-to-live-server)

it worked for me => open Devtools click the gear icon at right side scroll to bottom of settings click "restore defaults and reload"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34686660)

Comment: I just fixed it, thanks a lot, it really makes a lot of sense, I'm new here